# Block an Application for a certain amount of time

Tags: macos

Is there any application or any way to make me unable to open a software on my Mac for a determined amount of time (a self-imposed block)?

Why this? It's a poker software, and when things are going bad I want to exclude me from play for a certain amount of time (like 2 hours) to prevent the "tilt effect".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened to will power?

Comment: Have you ever played poker? Will poker dies sometimes :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [self control](http://visitsteve.com/made/selfcontrol/). It blocks websites rather than apps, but if you know where the app resolves to (I presume its online play) then you can block its access.

Next best thing is willpower.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, [a link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-apps-to-help-you-focus-be-productive-mac/) where you'll find 6 apps to help you focus your work. It goes from fading out all apps you DON'T want to use (and highlighting the apps you are allowed to use) to completely blocking all apps/websites you don't want them to use. You can even protect the session with a password.

So I think you are quite save with these apps :)